# If $u = 2 + 3i$ and $v = -5 + 4i$, then $u + v =$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have an exercise, it says:

If $u = 2 + 3i$ and $v = -5 + 4i$, then $u + v =$ ?

**My answer**: $$u + v = (2 - 5) + (3 + 4)i = -3 + 7i$$ 
but the correct answer is $7 - 3i$.

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Either the given answer is wrong, or there is a typo somewhere in the question.

Comment: I think my study material has had an error, thank you very much

Comment: The book must have mixed up real and imaginry parts.

Comment: Or maybe they meant $u - v$, but then the answer would be $7 - i$? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

We sum real and imaginary parts thus

$$2+3i-5+4i = -3+7i$$

There must be a typo in your study material.

Comment: I think my study material has had an error, thank you very much

Comment: `We sum real and imaginary parts` That's precisely what the OP did, if you look at the linked pic.

Comment: @Jav.dev yes of course!

Comment: @dxiv I just checked the sum!